# Upgraded Web Essentials 2012 and LESS stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

I recently upgraded Web Essentials 2012 from 2.7 to 3.7, and my LESS files no longer show the preview pane and do not generate a CSS file on save. I have the "Generate CSS file on save" option set to true, and I have Web Tools installed. Everything worked before I upgraded the extension.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

**Edit**

Is it possible to downgrade? I saw it's possible to download previous versions of Web Essentials 2013 from GitHub but not 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I found downloads for their older versions in the [changelog](http://vswebessentials.com/changelog). It didn't resolve my problem, but maybe it will help someone else.